PostgreSQL 15 create new role and owner doesn't work as expected
Hi community  I need your help.
I have PostgreSQL 15 sever that sits on AWS.
I have one user/role, let's call it (PMC); the admin role has all rights, plus each object owner in each schema on db server is PMC.
This is all I have from the previous DBA and DB developer.
I am trying to achieve next,

create a new role PMC_ADMIN that will inherit all rights from the role PMC but will not have the rights to create new schemas on DB.
When a new role PMC_ADMIN is created any object it must have an owner role/user PMC

To achieve that I have the next code:
CREATE ROLE pmc_admin INHERIT LOGIN PASSWORD '1234567890';

REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM pmc_admin;

-- Execute the command to add the pmc_admin role to the postgres role
GRANT pmc_admin TO postgres;

-- Set default privileges for the pmc_admin role to ensure it doesn't have the CREATE privilege on schemas
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE pmc_admin REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMAS FROM PUBLIC;

-- Set default privileges for the pmc_admin role to ensure objects are owned by pmc
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE pmc_admin
GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO pmc;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE pmc_admin
GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES TO pmc;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE pmc_admin
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO pmc;

--then i assign pmc_admin to user_testi
GRANT pmc_admin TO user_test;
However, I still can create schema if I log in as user_test, plus every object created by the user with the role pmc_admin has owner user_test.
Any help is appreciated
